# Migration from large tfs codebase using tfvc to using git still with tfs backend

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfvc

The organisation I work for are wanting to migrate their current code base from TFS (using TFVC) to Git but with the entire code base still residing in TFS. 
This needs to incorporate the developers who currently (majority) utilise Visual Studio 2010. We have explored options of using git plugins, git-tfs/git-tf command line tools but still without a definitive answer or a best approach to this. 
Essentially, Is there a way to successfully migrate from the two - without the need of copying the large code base (distributed style system with local copy of repo - which would be 30GB+ - not feasible on their VMs), and using the Visual Studio GUI tools for Git? If anyone has any ideas or opinions on this that would be a great help.

Comment: This question is pretty broad and unclear. Can you please add some more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish? (Please [edit] your post to add these details.)

Comment: I've editied the post. Should be more clarity now.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We are using TFS 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to migrate your TFVC team projects to Git team projects in TFS (require TFS 2013 or above version). The steps would be as below:

1. Create a new Team Project with GIT as version control in TFS.
2. Use [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) tool to clone all the projects to your local machine from TFVC Team Project:

> The optional --deep flag may be used to clone each TFS changeset for
>   the specified path into the new Git repo. If you don't need history, you can ignore this flag.

```
git tf clone http://myserver:8080/tfs/collectionName $/TeamProject [--deep]
```

3. Use [GIT BASH](https://git-scm.com/download/win) to push the cloned TFVC team project to the Git repository on TFS:

>

```
Git remote add http://TFSServerName:port/tfs/Collectionname/_git/GITRepositoryName

Git push origin master
```

Detailed steps you can refer to this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/05/19/migrating-a-tfvc-team-project-to-a-git-team-project-along-with-changeset-history-in-tfs/

After you migrate the TFVC team projects to Git team projects, you can install Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 to [start using Git in Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/get-started-vs2013).

Comment: That's a great starting point thank you - it doesn't fulfill the needs of my initial question though. In particular, some of our developers use Visual Studio 2010 and that our code base is big. One single repo is 20GB in size, so having a local copy of this on their machines is not really feasible - so does anyone recommend how best to tackle this?

Comment: There is no way to migrate team projects from TFVC to Git on server side directly. After you migrate the repo, you can delete the local repo, and your team member will be able to pull the repo they need on their local machine.

Comment: There is no way to clone a sub-directory of the repository through Visual Studio Git Plugins (in particular VS2010)? I know you can via CL git sparse checkout etc.

Comment: Instead of VS, you need to use CL to achieve the migration.